# Can't understand how to make istream manipulator

Tags: c++, io, iomanip, manipulators

I want to make an `int32_le_read(x)` manipulator that reads binary from a file and writes to `x`. I implemented the `int32_bin_manip` class

```cpp
class bin_manip
{
    public:
     bin_manip();
     ~bin_manip();
     friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is,bin_manip& obj);
     friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const bin_manip& obj);
     virtual std::ostream& write(std::ostream& os) const = 0;
     virtual std::istream& read(std::istream& is) = 0;
};

class int32_bin_manip : public bin_manip
{
    public:
        int32_t* x;
        int32_bin_manip(int& x);
        std::ostream& write(std::ostream& os) const;
        std::istream& read(std::istream& is);
};
```

for which `operator>>` and `operator<<` exist. How do I make a manipulator for `istream` of it now? For the `ostream` manipulator, I just created a function that returns an instance of this class and everything worked fine.

```cpp
int32_bin_manip write_le_int32(int& x)
{
    return int32_bin_manip(x);
}
```

But I can't do that with the `istream` manipulator, because its argument is `int32_bin_manip& obj`, unlike `const int32_bin_manip& obj`, which means I can't create a function that returns an instance of `int32_bin_manip` and use it like `istream >> int32_le_read(x)`, because it will bind the temporary instance to a non-const reference which is forbidden. So how do I need to implement such a manipulator?

Comment: These classes you are writing might be useful, but they are not manipulators. Manipulators don't read or write data, they modify the stream which is doing the reading or writing.

Comment: I don't see any reason you cannot change `friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is,bin_manip& obj);` to `friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is,const bin_manip& obj);`. Your 'manipulator' is `const` even though the data being read is not `const`.

Comment: @john Thank you! This worked with int32, but I have another manipulator, that works with string in C style (char*), and in this case I need to modify pointer to string (delete and allocate new space for it) that placed inside manipulator's class.

Comment: Well I guess you can pull the same trick, store a pointer to the pointer. At the very worst you can use `const_cast` (or even `mutable`). These options are OK as long as you don't use them to modify objects which are actually `const`. That would be undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't bind a non-`const` lvalue reference to a temporary, but you don't have to since you a not modifying the object itself but instead another object that it's pointing at, so make the `operator>>` take it by `const&` too:

```cpp
class bin_manip {
public:
    virtual ~bin_manip() = default; // <- added
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, const bin_manip& obj);
    //                                                ^^^^^ added
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const bin_manip& obj);

    virtual std::ostream& write(std::ostream& os) const = 0;
    virtual std::istream& read(std::istream& is) const = 0;
    //                                           ^^^^^ added
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/z8G55dE88)

Comment: Thank you! I understood this, but I think this solution won't work if I will do the same with a c-style string, because in this case I need to reallocate space for pointer. Sorry, of course I should have written about this in the question.

Comment: @MaxNov Hmm, I don't really see what that'd look like. Perhaps you could add it to the question too?

Comment: I found way how to solve this, I think now it's not worth adding this to the original question, but I'll explain what the problem was. I wanted to make similar manipulator, which must work like this: istream >> read_c_str(s), where s is (char*). In this case I have to save pointer to s in my manipulator class, and when >> operator called, the pointer must erase and then create again with new length (delete s; s = new char[size_of_string]), because of it I cant mark read function as a const.

Comment: But I found another way, I just use s as a buffer and allocate enough space for it at the declaration of s, and after i just fill this string with new character from istream,without reallocation for this pointer @Ted Lyngmo

Comment: @MaxNov `delete` should be `delete[]` in that case. I would however not assume that the `char*` is pointing at anything. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/rcn1eY5M7)

Comment: @MaxNov ... and it'd be much nicer with `std::string`s instead: [example](https://godbolt.org/z/M698Eq788)

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add another overload taking an rvalue reference to `int32_bin_manip`; rvalue references work as lvalue references to non-const inside the function body of a function with the rvalue reference as argument.

Note: `write` functionality removed for brevity in the following example, since there's no issue with using `const` in this case.

```
class bin_manip
{
public:
    virtual std::istream& read(std::istream& is) = 0;

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, bin_manip& obj)
    {
        obj.read(is);
        return is;
    }
};

class int32_bin_manip : public bin_manip
{
    int32_t& m_x;
public:
    constexpr int32_bin_manip(int32_t& x)
        : m_x(x)
    {
    }

    std::istream& read(std::istream& is) override
    {
        is >> m_x;
        return is;
    }

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, int32_bin_manip&& obj)
    {
        obj.read(is);
        return is;
    }
};

int main() {
    int32_t i;
    std::cin >> int32_bin_manip(i);
    std::cout << i << '\n';
}
```

Depending on your design you may want to introduce a function with 2 seperate overloads for `read` function calls on lvalues and rvalue references, if this suits your design better:

```
class bin_manip
{
public:
    virtual std::istream& read(std::istream& is) & = 0; // this one works just for lvalues, not for rvalue references

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, bin_manip& obj)
    {
        obj.read(is);
        return is;
    }
};

class rvalue_enabled_bin_manip : public bin_manip
{
public:

    using bin_manip::read;

    virtual std::istream& read(std::istream& is)&& // overload for rvalues
    {
        // fall back to standard, non-rvalue
        return read(is);
    }

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, rvalue_enabled_bin_manip&& obj)
    {
        std::move(obj).read(is);
        return is;
    }
};

class int32_bin_manip : public rvalue_enabled_bin_manip
{
    int32_t& m_x;
public:
    constexpr int32_bin_manip(int32_t& x)
        : m_x(x)
    {
    }

    std::istream& read(std::istream& is) & override
    {
        is >> m_x;
        return is;
    }
};
```